# 2560x1600 screens--dual monitor support possible?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

Anyone know if a regular gaming video card (VGA SAPPHIRE 100259-1GL HD4870) can support dual 2560x1600 monitors? I'm running on dual 1920x1200s right now and it's great, but that would be venturing into new territory for me. For the record, the system is running Windows 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No the dual link dvi connectors on the HD4870 support up to 2560x1600.  However I don't know of any monitor with 2560x1900 resolution, that is a very awkward aspect ratio.  Usually its 2560x1600 which is 16:10.

Source:
http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-4000/hd-4870/Pages/ati-radeon-hd-4870-specifications.aspx

Comment: Err--wow. My bad, I made the same typo twice. I meant 2560x1600! I'll edit the post now.

Comment: Well if its 2560x1600 then the HD4870 will support two of them. Though if you're planing on playing games at that resolution you'll most likely struggle with the newest games.

Comment: nah, the resolution is for work--documents, visual studio, design surfaces, etc. But hell, if I can get games to run at that resolution then all the better!